# Blitting the contents of Windows magnifier

Tags: c++, windows, api, bitblt, magnification

My Windows program copies the contents of windows using GetDC then BitBlt.  This works fine for most windows, but with magnifier windows I get a blank screen.  This happens whether it's a magnifier I create myself with the Magnification API or the built in Windows 7 magnifier.

Is this behavior by design, and is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is by design; magnifier windows don't draw the client area themselves; instead, they use [DWM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to copy/magnify some other area.  There's no public workaround; the bits are effectively being managed on the video card itself, and there's no backchannel available.